# Kerberos & Load Balancer

Tags: apache, kerberos, haproxy, high-availability

We are currently running a PHP application on apache httpd with mod_auth_kerb for SSO. We'd like to scale it to multiple hosts and make it highly available while we are at it.

Generally, HAproxy seems to be the recommended tool for this task, so i'll refer to this for the rest of the post - am open to alternatives here though. I haven't been able to find a way to combine HAproxy with Kerberos-based SSO - this seems to only be available for comercial load balancers (F5 for example).

We do not need the actual Kerberos ticket on the Webservers, it's literally just for authentication - is there a way to have HAproxy authenticate users via Kerberos and just pass the sAMAccountName as Header to the webservers? Alternatively full passthrough would work aswell of course.

Comment: Duh... A Kerberos service ticket is valid for a specific service on a specific server. KRB was never designed for distributed systems (like Hadoop) or load balancers. And even when connected to a single server, reaching to the KDC for each HTTP request is useless & inefficient.

Comment: That's why Hadoop RPC connections use Kerberos for initial auth only; then a *delegation token* is issued to the client for the rest of the session (and renewed via Kerberos if the session duration exceeds 10h). Hadoop REST connections and UIs work roughly the same way, except Kerberos is handled via SPNego, and the token is stored in a signed cookie on client side, so that it can be shared by multiple tabs (or parallel calls)

Comment: Did you get this working? If so, what were your steps?